# ERROR Error:Cannot find control with name: 'mark_each_qn'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

HTML

```
<form #form="ngForm" [formGroup]="sectionForm" #formDirective="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="setSections(sectionForm.value,null,formDirective)">
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" style="padding: 0px 16px;">
        <div class="title" fxFlex.gt-sm="50" fxFlex.gt-md="50" style="padding: 5px;">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required formControlName="name" matInput placeholder="Enter Section Name">
                <mat-error *ngIf="sectionForm.get('name').errors?.required">
                    Name is required.
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('name', 'required')">
                    {{"Please enter name"}}
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="title" fxFlex.gt-sm="50" fxFlex.gt-md="50" style="padding: 5px;">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input formControlName="instruction" required matInput placeholder="Enter Instructions">
                <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('instruction', 'required')">
                    {{"Please enter instruction"}}
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" style="padding: 0px 16px;">
        <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="isIndividualMark" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ngModelChange)="modelChangeFn($event)">
            Individual Mark
        </mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div id="mark" fxLayout="row wrap" style="padding: 0px 16px;margin-bottom: 50px;" fxLayoutAlign="end center">
        <div *ngIf="!isIndividualMark" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="50" fxFlex.gt-md="50" fxLayoutAlign="start center" style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: 900;">

            <span>Marks to each question</span>
            <mat-form-field style="text-align: right;width: 30px;margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;">

                <input min='0' type="number" matInput formControlName="mark_each_qn">
                <mat-error>
                    {{"Please enter a valid mark"}}
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <!-- <mat-error *ngIf="saveSection && (!cur_section.mark_each_qn || cur_section.mark_each_qn==0) ">
                                    {{"Please enter a valid mark"}}
                                 </mat-error> -->

        </div>
        <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="33" fxFlex.gt-md="50" fxLayoutAlign="end center" style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: 900;">
            Set Policy
            <mat-form-field style="text-align: right;width: 30px;margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;">
                <input require minlength="1" type="number" min="1" matInput [(ngModel)]="cur_section.mandatory_no" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
            </mat-form-field> / {{this.selectedQn.length}}
        </div>

    </div>
    <mat-error *ngIf="saveSection && selectedQn.length<1">
        {{"Please add atleast one question"}}
    </mat-error>
    <div style="min-height: 100px;max-height: 100px;overflow: auto;">
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" class="list" *ngFor="let questions of selectedQn  trackBy: let selected_qn_index = index;">
            <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="50" fxFlex.gt-md="10">
                {{selected_qn_index+1}}</div>
            <div id="text" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="50" fxFlex.gt-md="70" [innerHtml]="questions?questions.qn_desc:''">
            </div>
            <div id="form" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="50" fxFlex.gt-md="20" fxLayoutAlign="end center">

                <span>
                    <mat-form-field *ngIf="isIndividualMark" style="text-align: right;width: 25px;">

                        <input minlength="1" type="number" maxlength="3" min="0" matInput [(ngModel)]="questions.qn_mark" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                        <mat-error *ngIf="!questions.qn_mark || questions.qn_mark==0">
                            {{"error"}}
                        </mat-error>

                    </mat-form-field>
                </span>
                <span title="Click to deselect Question" (click)="unSelectQn(questions)">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="color: #e50303;">delete_forever</i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div fxLayout="row wrap" style="padding: 16px;" fxLayoutAlign="end center">
        <div style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: 900;">
            <span style="padding: 5px;">
                <button mat-raised-button type="button" color="primary" (click)="cancelSections(formDirective)">
                    Cancel
                </button>
            </span>
            <span style="padding: 5px;">
                <button mat-raised-button color="accent" [disabled]="!sectionForm.valid">
                    Add Section
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Ts file is

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.from_state = params['parent'];
  });

  this.resetSection();
  this.sectionForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    instruction: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  });
}



async setSections(sectionFormValue = null, type = "", formDirective: FormGroupDirective) {
  this.saveSection = true;
  if ((this.sectionForm.valid && this.selectedQn.length > 0) || type == "save_state") {
    if (sectionFormValue) this.cur_section = { ...this.cur_section, name: sectionFormValue.name, instruction: sectionFormValue.instruction, "qn_no": this.selectedQn.length, "questions": (type != "save_state") ? this.selectedQn : [], mark_each_qn: (!this.isIndividualMark ? sectionFormValue.mark_each_qn : 0) }
    this.qnSections = [...this.qnSections, this.cur_section]
    this.sectionData = {

      "title": this.qnPaperData.data.result ? this.basicData.question_paper_title : '',
      "qp_id": this.qpId,
      "is_practice": false,
      "user_id": this.userData.user_id,
      "time": this.time,
      "temp_sections": this.qnGroups,
      "sections": this.qnSections,
      "total_mark": 0
    }

    await this.assesmentService.saveSection(this.sectionData);
    this.saveSection = false;
    if (type != "save_state") {
      this.selectedQn = [];
      formDirective.resetForm();
      this.sectionForm.reset(this._initialValue)

      this.resetSection();
    }
    this.sectionData = {}
  } else {

  }
}
```

I found this problem in many questions in stackoverflow but no luck. Please help me for figuring out what I am doing wrong. I am new to angular

> The error occur when isIndividualMark become true . When submit is click it shows error while  isIndividualMark become false the code work perfectly. I tried many things but its not working for me . Sombody can help me?

Comment: You first need to start off deciding whether you want to use reactive forms or template driven forms. You should not use them together, so start off with deciding which you one to use even before asking this question, as you have bigger issues than the question at hand.

Comment: ... and actually by deciding which form you are going to use can very well actually solve your issue.